# Gaming using 2-port powerline: Lag spikes only when YouTube is running?

Tags: technical-issues, pc, counter-strike-global-offensive, performance

My S/O and I are currently using a 2-port powerline adapter, and we get speeds around 30up/30down with ~12 ping. It seems that our setup works completely fine except in the situation where someone is watching YouTube while the other is gaming.

Things that didn't cause lag spikes:

- Playing CS:GO at the same time
- 1 person playing CS:GO, the other watching Twitch in "Source" quality
- Both watching YouTube videos at the same time
- Both watching Twitch streams at the same time

Things that did:

- 1 person playing CS:GO, the other watching YouTube in any quality
  (tested in 1080p, 720, 360)

Does anyone know why this happens? It seems pretty bizarre to us.

Comment: Which game are you playing?  What quality of video are you watching from Youtube? That's going to be important information.

Comment: We are playing Counter-Strike: Global Offensive, and the lag occurs with YouTube videos of all qualities.

Comment: Only that game lags?  Do any others?

Comment: Haven't tried any other games, but we can try and see what happens!

Comment: Playing League of Legends with the other person watching a Twitch stream caused it the in-game ping to go from 60ms to ~80ms.

YouTube doesn't cause any noticeable ping increases, but the videos buffer very slowly.

I'm thinking this might be a Quality of Service problem but my router doesn't support QoS settings. :(

Comment: I'm thinking your ISP might be doing some QoS on their end, without telling you.  Nothing else seems to explain your symptoms.

Comment: youtube downloads faster than twitch because it buffers like a minute or something so your results don't really surprise me.

Comment: To reinforce what Aequittas mentioned the difference between YouTube and Twitch is YouTube (non streaming content) knows what is coming up next so will buffer video content at the other persons expense. given the speeds you have mentioned I am not surprised that it is having an impact.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks guys! I actually rectified the problem by changing the outlet the powerline connected to the modem was plugged into. The speeds are a lot more stable now, but I had to experiment with which outlet worked the best.

Comment: Also some powerline adaptors have built in QoS. It maybe it recognises youtube as streaming video site, and not twitch, so when someone watches youtube they get priority. If the adaptor came with any software, it's normally configurable via this.